# Screen not re-rendering even when the state is changed and screen is focused

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I am using useFocused from `react-navigation` to check when screen is focused.

#### If it is focused then fetch the latest conversations and set New state of conversations.

All of this is working perfectly but newly fetched conversations are not rendering on screen and old conversations are being rendered. (I am sure there is a change in conversation and state is updated because I have checked it thoroughly)

### I just don't understand why screen is not re-rendering when state is changed.

Following is the **code** for understanding:

```
const Chats = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const [User, setUser] = useUser();
  const [conversations, setConversations] = React.useState([]);
  const focused = useIsFocused();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (focused) {
      console.log("triggered");
      fetchConvos();
    }
    return () => {};
  }, [focused]);

  const fetchConvos = () => {
    fetch(IpAddress + User.userid + "/conversations", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      redirect: "follow",
      referrerPolicy: "no-referrer",
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((received) => {
        setConversations([...received]);
      });
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Header name={"Chats"} />
      <ScrollView style={styles.messageView}>
        {conversations.map((val) => {
          return (
            <ChatComponent
              conversation_name={val?.conversation_name}
              last_message={val.last_message}
              message_type={val.message_type}
            />
          );
        })}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: This has no effect with `React Navigation`. You need either to use a real-time solution like socket.io or Firebase.

Comment: It doesn't matter, the only problem is state is updating but screen not re-rendering.

Answer (score -1):

You overwrite your previous data when the fetch is resolved.
You should include the previous data when updating the state.

```js
setConversations((conversations) => [...conversations, ...received]);
```

Comment: I mean, that might be a bug, but its not in any way a resolution to his problem...

Comment: @Tomas No brother, what it will do is bring same conversations twice. This is not what I want.

Like If I have conversation with X and Y, it will show on screen like this:

`X Y X Y
`